# Taylor Diagram in R - averaging daily values

Tags: r

I'm a beginner at R and am trying to make Taylor diagrams to compare model and observational data. I have two data frames with daily temperature averages for model and obs data, but with different time ranges, so they have different lengths. I want to create a Taylor diagram with monthly averages drawn from the daily averages (so there will be 12 points for model and obs data on the Taylor Diagram).

I'm struggling to do this (I've looked into both openair and plotrix packages but am very confused). I tried creating a monthly average dataset and making Taylor diagrams off of these, but the standard deviation values with the openair TaylorDiagram function are drawn from the monthly averages, whereas I would like the SD to be drawn from the daily data instead.

Is there a way to input these two datasets of different lengths/time frames, and plot Taylor diagrams where monthly averages are visualized along with the SD capturing the variability in the daily averages?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow. Giving us only a written description of your problem without sample data and the code you are using makes it virtually impossible to give you a concrete answer in return that has a realistic chance of helping you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.8-2/topics/taylor.diagram)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.